# Failed to load Zend loader with Xampp

Tags: php, zend-guard

I am trying to load **zend guard loader** with xampp but it is not working any more.
I added code in php.ini file , restarted server.

**Php version 5.6.24 (Non-thread-safety)**
zend loader version is 5.6

```
[ZendGaurdLoader]
; ONLY PROVIDED UNDER PHP-FCGI
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\zend-loader\ZendLoader.dll"
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\zend-loader\php_opcache.dll"
zend_loader.enable=1
zend_loader.obfuscation_level_support=3
```

Any one have any idea please update.
I followed below link >

http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Guard/content/installing_zend_guard_loader.htm

[image: see result output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a big R & D, I found solution myself. It was version issues.
Actually Zend loader dll only support to 32 bit PHP version. So to fix it, I installed PHP 32 bit (Non thread safety) and then did required changes in PHP.ini file. Now all are working with Xampp.

Comment: this answer is deprecated